# textfield missing after hide keyboard [swift]

Tags: swift, textfield

I wanted to Move my view up only when the keyboard covers an input field but i wonder why my textfield gone missing after i hide the keyboard and i cannot fully scroll until the top when the keyboard is show. After i add this 2 functions of code:

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        if view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
        else {

        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
        if view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

[image: textfield]

Comment: do you have a solution for this??Cause I have the same problem

Comment: please refer to this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353774/element-at-the-bottom-of-view-disappear-after-hiding-the-keyboard-swift-4 hope can help u